# os.path.exists returns unexpected results

Tags: python

I want to execute a command after checking the directory in the python.

I am using

`if not os.path.exists(DIR2+dirName):`

if directory does not exist in the location 
then I want to create or move a directory to that location.

DIR2 is the path of the directory that I want to check. for example `/temp/test`
`dirName` is the name of the directory that I want to check for.

so in `/temp/test` I want to check if `/fold` exists.. if not than I want to create `/fold` in `DIR2` or move a directory from `DIR1` to `DIR2`

How can fix this if not statement? it looks like it goes inside of the loop no matter what..

Comment: try to start with `print DIR2+dirName`  at a guess `os.path.join(DIR2,dirName)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `os.path.join` to avoid errors due to string concatenation.

Also `os.path.isdir` will check for a folder (so you can also have a file named dirName in DIR2).

```
path = os.path.join(DIR2, dirName)
if not os.path.isdir(path):
    os.mkdir(path)
```